# Magento 2 installing PWA error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, pwa, pwa-studio

I am installing PWA

but facing below error when executing command

```
sudo yarn run build
```

Error:

```
As of version 12.1.0, PWA Studio requires the appropriate PWA metapackage to be installed on the backend.
For more information, refer to the 12.1.0 release notes here: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/releases/tag/v12.1.0
Error: Internal server error (... 1 errors total)
    at /pwa-studio/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:54:21
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getPossibleTypes (/pwa-studio/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:130:18)
    at async module.exports (/pwa-studio/webpack.config.js:79:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed below module on Magento:

```
composer require magento/module-upward-connector
```

**Disabled custom module**

then executed

```
yarn watch
```

Answer (score 1):

This is cause of url issues. also it's cause of the dependency. first you run the command in your magento

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

if it's running fine then try to run yarn watch in your PWA directory

Answer (score 0):

As the message mentioned, you need to take a look at the 12.1.0 release notes https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/releases/tag/v12.1.0.

According to the release notes, you must install the **Open Source metapackage** in all projects using PWA Studio 12.1.0 and higher.

You can see the instructions here https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/metapackages/open-source/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I also follow this for installation of the PWA:

https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-install-pwa-studio-in-magento-2-4/

If not works, please let me know. I will help you more about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer followed same step getting same error

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Updated question please check

Comment: Can you please try this 
https://www.mage2developer.com/setup-pwa-studio-with-magento-2/

Comment: This is the link which I used to install and it was working, Please follow this :
https://devhooks.in/blog/easiest-way-to-install-magento-2-pwa-studio

Answer (score 0):

I have installed metapackages only using the reference links shared here, but i still see this error, Please assist

root@localhost:/var/www/html/yuccapwa/pwa-studio# yarn run watch

yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack-dev-server --progress --color --env.mode development
As of version 12.1.0, PWA Studio requires the appropriate PWA metapackage to be installed on the backend.
For more information, refer to the 12.1.0 release notes here: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/releases/tag/v12.1.0
Error: Internal server error (... 1 errors total)
at /var/www/html/yuccapwa/pwa-studio/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:54:21
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async getPossibleTypes (/var/www/html/yuccapwa/pwa-studio/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:130:18)
at async module.exports (/var/www/html/yuccapwa/pwa-studio/webpack.config.js:79:27)
Done in 13.35s.